# Откуда пришло слово "дурак"?

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов

Я уже пытался отвечать на этот вопрос, 
но мой ответ был без объяснений удален модератором.

Как и многие ругательства, слово ДУРАК иностранного происхождения. 
В турецком есть целый куст слов на основе корня "дур" -- остановить.

дурмак (durmak) -- стоять... буква "м" просто выпала.

Но, придя в русский, это слово перестало быть глаголом и стало просто ругательством, 
и к тому же существительным... 
Но по сути мы продолжаем применять его правильно.

Когда кто то куда то ни туда лезет, то что мы ему кричим? 
Дурак! То есть остановись.

Доказательство? Да хотя бы посмотрите в любом электронном переводчике, 
слова с этим корнем в турецком языке весьма распространены 
и довольно часто употребляются.

Comment: Правильно удален. Никакой информативности в вашем ответе не было, даже версии не сформулированы.

Comment: Ваш вопрос не был удален без объяснения причин -- я прикрепил к нему уведомление, в котором содержится нужная вам информация. Ваш ответ не обоснован: в подтверждение вы приводите такие же некорректные факты.

Comment: >> *буква "м" просто выпала.* Дорогой друг @IgorTs79843, "просто" ничего не выпадает. )